# I need someting to instantly check that I have internet on Firefox or on Windows

Tags: windows-10, firefox, internet-connection, firefox-extensions

I'm working in an office with 5 coworkers. We all share the same internet connection. The connection enters a single PC in which we have created a hotspot and everyone access this PC through WIFI. We only have 3 collective internet hours a day. After that, if someone wants to use the internet, he must login with his personal account. When this happens **it is normally OK for the rest of the team members to share a bit of the private internet of the person who is using the personal account**, as long as they don't consume a substantial amount of the bandwidth.

The problem I'm facing is that, when a personal account is on, I have no instant way to know that internet is available. Sometimes it only lasts a few minutes or it is highly irregular. This is all decided by the owner who tries to save as much internet as possible so he connects and disconnects frequently to save internet time (In Cuba 1 hour of internet costs 1 dollar and the average salary is 25-30 dollars a month).

I tried to focus on bandwidth usage but it is not accurate as sometimes internet is on but no bandwidth consuming service is being used. For instance the owner is just using the chat.

Is there I way in which I could know with a precision of let's say a second that my PC has/ doesn't have internet access (either on my browser with an add on or in a Windows gadget). The little gray icon that comes with windows (by the clock on the bar) is highly inaccurate in this. I'm not interested at all in measuring my internet speed.

I know I could always open the browser and google something but I'm looking for a more automated alternative. In the end I might have to create a service that executes every second(or every 10 seconds) and checks for internet and visually reports it in a floating widget. But maybe this already exists.

I don't really care not knowing how long that personal account might last. Because while it is ON I can perform short routine tasks such as download emails or check for new questions on StackO which answer I can type while offline , etc. Having the opportunity to immediately (few seconds) know when internet is available is what I'm looking for.

Comment: `ping 8.8.8.8` is a pretty good indicator. if the internet is working you will get a reply in < 1s.

Comment: Nice idea. I would have to encapsulate this in a script or a service to make it work automatically

Comment: [Here is one](https://www.giga.de/downloads/wlan-status-gadget/)  If that would be good enough, I can write an answer in English...

Comment: @Fabby jajaja Danke. Ich habe gedacht es war auf Spanisch! I could download it but it doesn't work on my Windows 10. Maybe because it is from 2008

Comment: Then @DavidPostill's idea is the best.  I could write a .cmd file for you that checks every second and can alert everyone that the Internet is on except the owner if you add the hostnames of everyone to the question. (if David doesn't want to do this himself, as he was the first to respond) The .cmd file will be compatible with Windows 4 up to Windows 10 and beyond...

Comment: @Fabby Nice! Go ahead! But how would it alert everyone? Would I need to have the cmd opened all the time? Just to know. It wouldn't be a problem. As long as it notifies me it is just fine, the others would be an excellent bonus though.

Comment: If someone logs on with their personal account, you don't know how long that connection will last, even if you test for the presence of a connection right now.  It isn't clear what this buys you.

Comment: @fixer1234 I don't really care not knowing how long that personal account might last. Because while it is ON I can perform short routine tasks such as download emails or check for new questions on StackO which answer I can type while offline , etc. Having the opportunity to immediately (few seconds)  know when internet is available is what I'm looking for. Do you understand now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open Notepad and copy-paste the following text into it:

```
@ECHO OFF
:Retry
PING -n 1 -w 2000 1.1.1.1
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO Retry

ECHO "Internet ON!"
```

Save it on your desktop as `InternetON.CMD` and double-click it.

If it shows a black screen, with something moving every 2 seconds, you're all set!

If it just shows the text above again, open a command prompt and type:

```
CD %USERPROFILE%\Desktop
REN InternetON.CMD.txt InternetON.CMD
EXIT
```

Now you're all set! Just double-click it again.

**Optional:** To add a beep when the Internet comes on, you have to open a command prompt again and type:

```
ECHO Ctrl+G >> %userprofile%\Desktop\InternetON.CMD
```

Right-click the file and edit again and move the funny square to just right after the last `"`

If the Internet starts working, it'll warn you and when you notice the Internet is off again, just double-click it again.  Not a beautiful gadget, but it does everything you need!

Answer (score 1):

Inspired on the answer so nicely carried out by Fabby I want to post my own adaptation of his answer:

I customized some things. For instance, instead of a beep I have recorded two .mp3 audios. One that signals that the internet is ON and one that signals that it is OFF. I found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23313709/play-invisible-music-with-batch-file) the way to play invisible music (it works on Windows 10). I modified the original script proposed by Fabby to keep track of when I have or I don't have internet. I had to switch to 8.8.8.8 DNS as originally suggested by DavidPostil because while the internet is OFF the address 1.1.1.1 has an actual meaning in my network

```
@ECHO OFF

:whileNoInternet

set "host=8.8.8.8"

::check if internet is working

PING -n 1 -w 5000 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% neq 0 (

    ::the internet is not working keep cheking until it does
    echo No internet yet %TIME%
    GOTO whileNoInternet
)

echo we gained internet
::the internet is working play internet ON song

@echo off
set "file=InternetON_GOGOGO.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs


@ECHO OFF


:whileInternet

sleep.exe 5s

::check if internet is still working

PING -n 1 -w 1000 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"


if %errorlevel% == 0 (

    ::the internet is still working keep cheking until it does not
    echo We have internet %TIME%
    GOTO whileInternet
) 


:: detect possible internet glitches (do not trust the first failure)
echo internet glitch detected

sleep.exe 10s

PING -n 1 -w 1000 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (

    ::the internet is still working keep cheking until it does not
    echo We have internet %TIME%
    GOTO whileInternet
) 

:: if it failed twice in a row most likely internet is down


echo we lost internet
::the internet is not working anymore, play internet OFF song

@echo off
set "file=InternetHasFallen.mp3"
( echo Set Sound = CreateObject("WMPlayer.OCX.7"^)
  echo Sound.URL = "%file%"
  echo Sound.Controls.play
  echo do while Sound.currentmedia.duration = 0
  echo wscript.sleep 100
  echo loop
  echo wscript.sleep (int(Sound.currentmedia.duration^)+1^)*1000) >sound.vbs
start /min sound.vbs



::start monitoring if it comes back
GOTO whileNoInternet
```

Comment: Just download `sleep.exe` from the [GNU Core Unix utilities for Windows](http://unxutils.sourceforge.net/) to include a waiting time... **0:-)**